# Merging tables in t-sql

Tags: t-sql, merge

I have a table holding periods and prices, something like this

```
itemid periodid    periodstart     periodend     price
1      1           2011/01/01      2011/05/01    50.00
1      2           2011/05/02      2011/08/01    80.00
1      3           2011/08/02      2011/12/31    50.00
```

Now I have a second table that can hold single dates or periods

```
itemid periodid periodstart periodend    price
1      8        2011/07/01  2011/07/17   70.00
```

Now, how can I do a query that would return the following result?

```
itemid periodid    periodstart     periodend     price
    1      1           2011/01/01      2011/05/01    50.00
    1      2           2011/05/02      2011/06/30    80.00 ****
    1      8           2011/07/01      2011/07/17    70.00  ***
    1      2           2011/07/18      2011/08/01    80.00 ****
    1      3           2011/08/02      2011/12/31    50.00
```

EDIT -- Highlight the fact that the merge is modifying the dates around it

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
select 
 t1.itemid,t1.periodid,t1.periodstart, coalesce(dateadd(d,-1,t2.periodstart),t1.periodend) as periodend, t1.price
 from t1
 left outer join t2 on t1.periodstart < t2.periodstart and t1.periodend>t2.periodstart and t1.itemid=t2.itemid
 union
select 
 t2.itemid,t2.periodid,t2.periodstart, t2.periodend, t2.price
 from t1
 inner join t2 on t1.periodstart < t2.periodstart and t1.periodend>t2.periodstart and t1.itemid=t2.itemid
 union
select 
 t1.itemid,t1.periodid,dateAdd(d,1,t2.periodend), t1.periodend, t1.price
 from t1
 inner join t2 on t1.periodstart < t2.periodend and t1.periodend>t2.periodend and t1.itemid=t2.itemid

order by periodstart
```

Comment: This looks good, but I have to check it better, because there is inconsistency with border periods and duplicate periods.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Union?

```
 Select itemid, periodid,periodstart, periodend,price FROM table1
 UNION
 SELECT itemid, periodid,periodstart, periodend,price FROM table2
```

Are you trying to do some sort of join though?  the result set doesn't match the two tables you supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accounting for entries that line up or are you just trying to combine the rows?

if the latter, you could just do a Union

```
Select itemid, periodid, periodstart, periodend, price 
From Table1
Union
Select itemid, periodid, periodstart, periodend, price 
From Table2
```